# setInterval Firing too Often (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I have been trying to write code for a simple countdown timer that I am making for a website (take a look here: sbtimescore.github.io). Unfortunately, I've run into a logical error my limited knowledge can't solve (I'm a newbie). When one presses the start/pause repeatedly, the timer starts to speed up. I have posted the code for which is run onclick() below:

```
function spGameClock() {
  if (gameClockRunning == false) {
    gameClockRunning = true;
  } else {
    gameClockRunning = false;
    return;
  }

  function timer() {
    if (gameCounter == 0) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      $("#GameClockText").html(secondsToText(gameCounter));
      blinkIt("GameClockBox");
    } else if (gameCounter > 0 && gameClockRunning == true) {
      $("#GameClockText").html(secondsToText(gameCounter));
      gameCounter = gameCounter - 1;
    } else if (gameCounter > 0 && gameClockRunning == false) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    } else {}
  }

  var interval = setInterval(timer, 1000);
}
```

I know that the interval is being called too many times, but I'm not sure how to fix it. If anyone has a solution, I would be grateful.

Comment: Don't worry about the blinkIt function or the secondsToText function; those call other functions elsewhere in the js document.

Comment: spGameClock being called more than one time?

Comment: looks like every time you click the button you create another interval

Comment: Is `gameClockRunning` global?

Comment: Have you considered changing it to use setTimeout and only perpetuating the timeout loop if the conditions still call for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define `interval` as a variable outside of the `spGameClock` function. A good place would be within the jQuery `ready` callback. You could then also use that variable itself to determine whether the clock is ticking or not.

Here is an implementation using countdownjs:

```js
$(function () {    
    var interval = null, // define outside of spGameClock scope
        gameCounter = 10; // Some initial value

    function spGameClock() {
      // Use interval as detection:
      if (interval == null) {
        interval = setInterval(timer, 1000);
        $("#GameClockText").text(secondsToText(gameCounter));
      } else {
        clearInterval(interval);
        interval = null; // Always set to null after clearing
        $("#GameClockText").text(secondsToText(gameCounter) + " (paused)");
      }

      function timer() {
        gameCounter--;
        $("#GameClockText").text(secondsToText(gameCounter));
        // No need to test interval for null here, since it certainly is not.
        if (gameCounter <= 0) {
          clearInterval(interval);
          interval = null;
          blinkIt("GameClockBox");
        }
      }
    }

    // Attach event handler here instead of using onclick attribute
    $("#toggle").click(spGameClock);
    // Start clock now
    spGameClock();

    // Utility functions:
    function secondsToText(sec) { // Uses countdown library:
        return countdown(new Date().getTime() + 1000*sec).toString() || "Game Over!";
    }

    function blinkIt(id) {
        (function loop(times) {
            if (times) $('#' + id).fadeToggle(400, loop.bind(null, times-1));
        })(6);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/countdown/2.6.0/countdown.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="toggle">Pause/Continue</button>

<div id="GameClockBox">
    <div id="GameClockText"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could the downvoter be kind enough to explain what the problem is?

Comment: Not me, but possibly for suggesting a global var (despite the disclaimer)

Comment: @trincot Is there a reason that we need to define the entire thing inside an encapsulating function?

Comment: It is only necessary if the script is not at the end of the body tag: if put elsewhere, then some elements might not yet have been loaded when the script tries to access them. The callback to `$( )` will only be executed when the document is ready. Secondly it provides a closure for the variables like `interval`: otherwise you would have to declare them as global variables, which might not be the nicest solution.